# Expanding an array of objects stored in JSONB

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I've got a table that includes a JSONB field with a JSON array with a simple format that I'd like to expand. Here's a slimmed version of the table's definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.data_file_info (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    server_name_ citext NOT NULL,
    table_stats jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Here's a bit of sample data from the table_stats JSONB field:

```
[
    {"table_name":"AutoReportOrg","record_count":48,"table_number":167},
    {"table_name":"AutoReportOrgAudit","record_count":0,"table_number":170},
    {"table_name":"AutoReportOrgRecipient","record_count":126,"table_number":168},
    {"table_name":"AutoReportRecipient","record_count":28,"table_number":169}
]
```

The [json_populate_recordset](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) and/or [json_to_recordset](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) functions seem like they should be what I'm after, but I haven't been able to get them working. I've looked at a lot of past questions, and tried out various bits of syntax. Below is what I get the impression should work...but it isn't:

```
-- Define a custom type to act as a template for the JSON parser.
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS dfits;
CREATE TYPE api.dfits AS (
    table_name citext,
    record_count int8,
    table_number int4);

-- And now we parse!
SELECT server_name_, (json_populate_recordset(null::dfits, table_stats)).* FROM data_file_info;
```

But I get this back:

```
ERROR:  function json_populate_recordset(dfits, jsonb) does not exist
LINE 4: SELECT server_name_, (json_populate_recordset(null::dfits, t...
                              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (Line 9)
```

Can anyone spot the error in my setup? It seems like I've got the right pieces, but I'm not managing to put them together properly.

Postgres 11.4, deployed on RDS.

### Follow Up

GMB answered my question, but I want to add a bit more here for the archives. Past my typing error (JSON instead of JSONB), the crux of this stuff seems to be that Postgres needs a template/map that defines the structure of the elements in the JSON/JSONB array. I think that there are four (?) places that typing data can come from in this case:

- An existing table definition, as each table is a type.
- An existing view definition, as each view is a type. (You can find them in [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) along with base table-derived types.
- A custom type created with `CREATE TYPE`, like I used above.
- An in-line declaration.

For comparison, here's an updated query that uses the custom type `dfits` shown above:

```
SELECT server_name_, expanded_json.*
FROM
   data_file_info, 
   jsonb_populate_recordset(null::dfits, table_stats) as expanded_json
```

And now here's another version that uses an in-line declaration:

```
SELECT server_name_, expanded_json.*
FROM
   data_file_info, 
    jsonb_to_recordset(table_stats) as expanded_json 
        (table_name text, record_count int, table_number int)
```

I can see uses for either approach. But, with that said, `CREATE TYPE` is pretty great. And you can combine it with `CREATE CAST` to make for very compact and easy-to-use code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your are using a `jsonb` column, you actually need `jsonb_populate_recordset`. Also, this function returns a set of records, so it needs to be placed in the `FROM` clause, not in the `SELECT` clause.

Consider:

```
SELECT server_name, x.*
FROM
   data_file_info, 
   jsonb_populate_recordset(null::dfits, table_stats) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ggS7895qF83Japa1sJUCcX/0)**:

```
| server_name | table_name             | record_count | table_number |
| ----------- | ---------------------- | ------------ | ------------ |
| foo         | AutoReportOrg          | 48           | 167          |
| foo         | AutoReportOrgAudit     | 0            | 170          |
| foo         | AutoReportOrgRecipient | 126          | 168          |
| foo         | AutoReportRecipient    | 28           | 169          |
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's perfect.